# Getting coordinates of mouse click on grid easy java StdDraw

Tags: java, mouseevent, stdin, stddraw

okay so I am trying to get the coordinates on a grid of which square a mouse was clicked on (why i casted into int) and this is giving me like the current position of the mouse,however, I want the position after a click and for nothing to happen while it hovers.

what do i need to do?

```
while (gameOver==false){
    mouseX= (int) StdDraw.mouseX();
    mouseY=(int) StdDraw.mouseY();
    game.update(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

now i have

```
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
       int mouseX = e.getX();
       int mouseY = e.getY();
               synchronized (mouseLock) {
    mousePressed = false;
}
}
public void run(){
    print();
    boolean gameOver=false;
    int mouseX,mouseY;
    StdDraw.setCanvasSize(500, 500);
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, game.gettheWidth());
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, game.gettheHeight());
    game.update(-1,-1);
    while (gameOver==false){

            mouseReleased(????)
            game.update(mouseX, mouseY);
        }       

}
```

still not working

None of this is making sense still,

Could someone give me an example of it getting x and y coordinates then printing them?
I want the mouseX and mouseY to the be coordinates of the mouseclick. I've looked online I don't understand any of the other questions, I assume it has something to do with mouseevent?

Answer (score 0):

StdDraw implements a MouseListener. Overload the mouseReleased method to set your mouseX and mouseY variables.

To overload, your rewrite the method the way you need it to run:

```
int mouseX = 0;
int mouseY = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //do stuff
    //...
    while (gameOver == false) {
        //because mouseX and mouseY only change when the mouse button is released
        //they will remain the same until the user clicks and releases the mouse button
        game.update(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}

//mouseReleased happens whenever the user lets go of the mouse button
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    //when the user lets go of the button, send the mouse coordinates to the variables.
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();
    synchronized (mouseLock) {
        mousePressed = false;
    }
}
```

So for example, mouseX and mouseY are both 0. I click the mouse at `5, 6`, drag it, and release the mouse at `120, 50`. mouseReleased is called and changes mouseX to 120, and mouseY to 50. Meanwhile, game.update(0,0) has been happening. That now changes into game.update(120, 50), and will remain that way until I release the mouse button again.

To print the mouse coordinates:

```
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    //when the user lets go of the button, send the mouse coordinates to the variables.
    System.out.println("mouse x coord = " + e.getX());
    System.out.println("mouse y coord = " + e.getY());
    synchronized (mouseLock) {
        mousePressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does "overload the mousereleased method" mean?

Comment: Your write a new version of it. I've edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: I can't see it, assume your still typing it? thanks a ton appreciate it

Comment: while (gameOver==false){
   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
       mouseX = e.getX();
       mouseY = e.getY();
   }
   game.update(mouseX, mouseY);
  }

Comment: No, you don't need to put the method in your game loop; the `mouseReleased` method is called whenever the user lets go of the mouse button. Your game loop would be exactly the same as in your question, minus the lines to set `mouseX` and `mouseY`

Comment: edited my answer still trying to understand your helping

Comment: okay so now how do i acess the x and y coordinates i will edit again with what I am trying to do. Sorry ughh so confusing! not your answer.

Comment: check out what i have now maybe you can give me further direction

Comment: okay so none of this is making any sense where is the mouseclick taking place can you add comments or something. and how do i access e.getY and e.getY in the main?

Comment: all i want is an example of it getting x and y coordinates and printing them could you do that?